# AR(1) with x-dependent parameter

Tags: stationarity, autoregressive

Let us consider the following model: $$ x_{t} = \alpha + \beta x_{t-1} + v_{t} $$ where $v_{t} \in \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^{2})$.

I'm interested in the steady state distribution of $x$ if $\beta$ can take two values -- $\beta_{l}$ and $\beta_{h}$ ($0 < \beta_{l} < \beta_{h} < 1$) -- in the following way: if $x_{t-1}$ is below the median of the distribution of $x_{t-1}$ values then $\beta = \beta_{l}$; if it is above the median then $\beta = \beta_{h}$.

From numerics I know that the steady-state distribution exists, and it is not too different from the normal distribution that corresponds to a fixed $\beta=1/2\cdot(\beta_{l} + \beta_{h})$. Any help regarding a closed-form formula?

Thanks!